# Get the window of a Direct3D9 device

Tags: c++, window, directx, direct3d, wndproc

I'm hooking a Direct3D9 device by searching for the VTable and appending my own method to the start of selected referenced functions with a detour.

```
D3DEndScene = (lpfnD3DEndScene)((LPVOID)dwVTable[VD3D_ENDSCENE]); // 35 dx8
D3DResetDevice = (lpfnD3DResetDevice)((LPVOID)dwVTable[VD3D_RESET]); // 14 dx8

DetourTransactionBegin();
DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)D3DEndScene, D3DEndScene_Hook);
DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)D3DResetDevice, D3DResetDevice_Hook);

DetourTransactionCommit();
```

That's working fine.

As a result I have access to the Direct3D9 device I've called "pDevice".

```
HRESULT WINAPI D3DEndScene_Hook (LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice)
```

I would like to extract the window handle that pDevice is using so that I can hook the WndProc attribute and filter out keyboard/mouse events (and handle them myself). I know I can use SetWindowLong to find the existing WndProc, but I've no idea how to actually get any form of window handle out of the device.

What I do know is that in the method IDirect3D9::CreateDevice there is the argument hFocusWindow which seems like what I'm looking for; but I've no idea how to access it after creation.

Hooking CreateDevice isn't a very good option for me because I won't be hooking until far after the device is created and hence I won't catch the function in time.

How can I get the window handle of a D3D9 device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for D3D9:

[IDirect3DDevice9::GetCreationParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174382%28v=vs.85%29)

You can use that to get the creation paramaters used to create the device including hFocusWindow.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is possible that the window handle was not passed as an argument to `CreateDevice`, but as part of the `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` struct, in which case your method will return `NULL`.

Comment: What about D3D10 or DXGI?